# how to make table header fixed in html without using thead tag?

Tags: html, css

I have the following table which do not have thead:

```html
    <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr class="header">
       <th>Head 1</th>
       <th>Head 2</th>
       <th>Head 3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>body</td>
       <td>body</td>
       <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>body</td>
       <td>body</td>
       <td>body</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>body</td>
       <td>body</td>
       <td>body</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>

CSS:

.table tr td {
    overflow-y: auto    
}
.table tr.header th {
    display: block;
}
```

So how to fix the table header in above table.

Comment: When you clearly have a header there, why not mark it as such and not have this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is make the main body a `display: block`, then you can use `overflow: auto` on it. But you want to keep `.header` dont scroll with other `<tr>`s so you need to move `.header` out.

I have updated my jsFiddle if you can accept move `.header` out of `<tbody>`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gc6m0g3L/)

```
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(1),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 200px;
}
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(2),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(2) {
  min-width: 200px;
}
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(3),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 350px;
}
.fixed_headers {
    width: 750px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.fixed_headers th, .fixed_headers td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}
.fixed_headers .header {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #fdfdfd;
}
.fixed_headers tr
{
    display: block;
}
.fixed_headers tbody:last-of-type{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Great! Also you did not use thead in css. But if thead is removed in html means it do not work please check and tell

Comment: Can you move `.header` out of the `<tbody>`?